# How to change content view background colour of destination ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, background-color, didselectrowatindexpath

I am using a Master-detail `ViewController` with many rows holding titles in masterviewcontroller and I want to change the content view background color of the detail `ViewController` cells based on which rows were selected by the user in Master `ViewController`. It's like a book in which master view controller holds the chapter's title and when the user selects a chapter, it can read that chapter in the detail view controller. 
User won't select any cells but i will user `NSTimer` to highlight and dehighlight rows in detail `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a property in the .h file of your detail view that will determine the color you want. Then in prepare for segue in your tableviewcontroller you can create an instance of the detail viewcontroller and set the property:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DetailViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
    dest.myBackgroundColorProperty = [UIColor redColor];
}
```